# Contruct a <select> that show courses IN specific category and category childrens too

Tags: moodle

i'm using Moodle 2.9.7

I would like to get a list of courses in a specific category also with courses in children categories of the categories( if exist some ).

this is should be made in a  where the options would be course list

I'm practically new with moodle so cannot imagine or set a clue how i would do this.

if anyone could help would be wonderful.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the top of my head I'd go with something like this:

```
$categoryid = 1; // Change this.
$category = coursecat::get($categoryid);
$childrencategories = $category->get_children();
$coursesincategory = $category->get_courses();
```

The advantage of using `coursecat` is that it will not display categories not visible to the current user.

To construct the select box you may decide to use `html_writer` or a `select` element when extending the `moodleform` class. There are many examples of the latter in Moodle.

**Test file**

Here is a test file you can name `test_coursecat.php` and place at the root of your Moodle, where `index.php` is. Access it via `yoursiteurl/test_coursecat.php`, you can optionally add `?categoryid=NUMBERHERE` to change the category to start from.

```
<?php

// Require config.php, and coursecatlib.
require('config.php');
require($CFG->libdir . '/coursecatlib.php');

// Get the parameter 'categoryid' passed via GET parameter. Else the value will be 0.
$categoryid = optional_param('categoryid', 0, PARAM_INT);

// Require a user to be logged in to access this page.
require_login();

// Set the minimal page requirements.
$PAGE->set_context(context_system::instance());
$PAGE->set_url('/test_coursecat.php');

// Start the output.
echo $OUTPUT->header();

// Fetch out root category with ID $categoryid.
$rootcategory = coursecat::get($categoryid);

// Get 2 sub categories.
$categories = $rootcategory->get_children(array('limit' => 2));

// Output each category fetched, and their associated courses.
echo '<pre>';
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo $category->name . PHP_EOL;

    foreach ($category->get_courses() as $course) {
        echo ' - ' . $course->shortname . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
echo '</pre>';

// End the output.
echo $OUTPUT->footer();
```

Comment: reading on here [link](http://fossies.org/dox/moodle-2.9.6/classcoursecat.html#a5a3bd85bd87b793d61d3bc3f72804329) it says is posible to use a children limit . this would a correct way? $childrencategories = $category->get_children(array('limit'=>4));

Comment: Yes, I've updated the description to add a test script you can use.

Comment: actually your answer before was enought but I completlely forgot to accept it. Thanks so much . Anytway the rest is valid for more people.